# Search for a url on a page whose url contains 2 separate words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to get my chrome extension to look for a URL which contains some variable on a page with jquery and regex. I have:

```
var kwregexstring = jacket;
var colorregexstring = black;

var url = $('a[href*=' + kwregexstring + ']:first').prop("href");
if (url){
window.alert("" + url);
};
```

What I would like to do is find the first link that contains both the keyword and the color and I'm just not sure how to do it. Currently it finds the first link with the keyword just fine. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) selector.  This isn't too bad, actually:

```
 $('a[href*="' + kwregexstring + '"][href*="'+ colorregexstring +'"]:first')
```

Note that these aren't regexes.  You're doing a substring pattern match.  What is happening is you're running 3 seperate selectors:

**a** - an element tag specifier

**[href*="keyword"]** - an XPath style query, which looks for elements with an href attribute which contains the keyword substring.

**[href*="color"]** - an XPath style query, which looks for elements with an href attribute which contains the color substring.

Since this is a joined query (just like something like div.myClass would be), your result set is the items which match ALL of the selectors.  From there, you run the :first psuedo-selector and you've got your element.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately I'm getting undefined returned with this. I made sure that there was an element with both substrings on the page.

Comment: Undefined?  Are you using jQuery?  Even if it couldn't find anything, jQuery would return a jQuery object with 0 length.